# SQL Server memory limit solution

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server express editions have memory limit of 1GB. Can I install multiple versions of SQL Servers say SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008, both express editions on same machine and expect that both will use 1GB memory limit separately. Is it true? I have two DBs and I can attach one to 2005 edition and other to 2008 edition. Any suggestion please. Will it work or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

A SQL Server install is called an "instance", which allows you to have multiple instances various versions (including the same one).

My recommendation would be that if you aren't using an instance, that it not be turned on or it'll be reserving memory that could be used for other things.

Comment: To be more specific, SQL Server express allows multiple instances (I think 16).  There's no need to mix versions.

Comment: @Donnie: So does Workgroup, Standard, Developer, Enterprise... what's your point?

Comment: @Ponies -In the question he talked about mixing versions to get multiple instances.  I was just expressly pointing out that this wasn't necessary since Express didn't limit number of instances.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't have to mix the versions if the same version can solve my purpose.